# SICP exercise 4.5

Tags: scheme, computer-science, sicp

I'm learning SICP and do the programming exercises. I have a question about exercise 4.5. The exercise 4.5 is:

> Scheme allows an additional syntax for `cond` clauses, `(<test> => <recipient>)`. If `<test>` evaluates to a true value, then `<recipient>` is evaluated. Its value must be a procedure of one argument; this procedure is then invoked on the value of the `<test>`, and the result is returned as the value of the `cond` expression. For example:

```
(cond 
  ((assoc 'b '((a 1) (b 2))) => cadr)
  (else false))
```

As shown above,if `<test>` is true,the value of the `cond` clause should be `(<recipient> <test>)` (i.e.

> then `<recipient>` is evaluated. Its value must be a procedure of one argument; this procedure is then invoked on the value of the `<test>`, and the result is returned...

But when I search the solution on the Internet, almost all I found are `(list (extended-cond-recipient first) (extended-cond-test first))`. **It's a list consist of `<recipient>` and `<test>`** , **not a function call**.
What should I do? It has troubled me a long time...

Comment: The "additional syntax" is not commonly used, almost everyone just uses the basic syntax. So it's not surprising you can't find much about it.

Answer (score 2):

In [The Core of the Evaluator](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-26.html#%_sec_4.1.1),  under “Special Forms”, is written:

> • A case analysis (cond) is transformed into a nest of if expressions and then evaluated.

That is, first a transformation at the program level is done, and only after this transformation the resulting expression is evaluated. The transformation is done by the function `cond->if`, which *does not evaluate* the cond expression, only transform it in a nested list containing multiple `if`. This can be seen in the definition of the eval function, where there is the case:

```
((cond? exp) (eval (cond->if exp) env))
```

In the solutions that you have seen, the `cond->if` function is modified so that it transforms the `=>` syntax in a list (as you have correctly observed), a list that contains the function as first element, and its argument as second element, and *that list* will be evaluated correctly *in the subsequent steps* of the interpreter.

Comment: emm...the code example of the sicp is `(cond ((assoc 'b'((a 1) (b 2)))=> cadr) (else false)) `.As shown above,`(list (extended-cond-recipient first) (extended-cond-test first))`,is finally executed `(list cadr '(b 2))`.It's the **expression sequences**,and the value is the last sequence,i.e `(b 2)`.I think the answer should be like `(apply <recipient> <test>)`,rather than `(list <recipient> <test>)`.I've tried it,but failed...

Comment: The result of `list cadr '(b 2))` is: `(cadr '(b 2))`, which is evaluated to 2 *only* when everything is expanded, by the line that I cited in the answer (the part `(eval (cond-if exp) env)`. I do not understand what are you trying to do: when the exercise says: “Modify the handling of cond” it means: modify the function `cond->if`. And in that function *there is no evaluation or application*. It is like a macro which is expanded, and the treatment of the `=>` syntax must be done at that level. *Nothing* must be evaluated or applied during such expansion.